# Seven Segment display VHDL code issue

Tags: vhdl, output, 7segmentdisplay

i am trying to use a seven segment display to show the numbers 0 to 9, using BCD and the dip switch the FPGA Board includes to determine the High and Lows. I found some relevant code but, my FPGA has some additional pins, in order to display the numbers. Here is the code :

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity  seven_segments is
port (
      clk : in std_logic;
        bcd : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);  --BCD input
        segment7 : out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0)  -- 7 bit decoded output.
    );
end seven_segments;
--'a' corresponds to MSB of segment7 and g corresponds to LSB of segment7.
architecture Behavioral of seven_segments is

begin
process (clk,bcd)
BEGIN
if (clk'event and clk='0') then
case  bcd is
when "0000"=> segment7 <="0000001";  -- '0'
when "0001"=> segment7 <="1001111";  -- '1'
when "0010"=> segment7 <="0010010";  -- '2'
when "0011"=> segment7 <="0000110";  -- '3'
when "0100"=> segment7 <="1001100";  -- '4'
when "0101"=> segment7 <="0100100";  -- '5'
when "0110"=> segment7 <="0100000";  -- '6'
when "0111"=> segment7 <="0001111";  -- '7'
when "1000"=> segment7 <="0000000";  -- '8'
when "1001"=> segment7 <="0000100";  -- '9'
 --nothing is displayed when a number more than 9 is given as input.
when others=> segment7 <="1111111";
end case;
end if;

end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Below are the pins for the display, i want to use Dig1, but i am not sure how to add it to the code, so i won't have to remove a Segment.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: In general you can simply expand your entity by adding another signal and make sure the port naming is reflected correctly in the pin assignment. But maybe you can be a bit more specific what you mean by "I want to use Dig1". And what dev board are you using?

Comment: The dev board i am using is [this](https://makerselectronics.com/product/rz-easy-fpga-a2-2-development-board)
So i should add something called lets say DIG1 at the entity, and simply assign pin 133 there?

Comment: Pin assignment doesn't happen in the entity but in a separate file respectively if you're using quartus it's called `assignment editor`. You should find `SEG0` to `SEG7` in there. By the way, is this your `top_entity` file?

Comment: Yes i know pin assignment doesn't happen there, i meant in the pin planner/assignment editor.

I got the code from [here](https://vhdlguru.blogspot.com/2010/03/vhdl-code-for-bcd-to-7-segment-display.html), so i guess that's the top entity file?

Comment: Most likely then... so let us know if you're facing any specific issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a complete answer, you should give us more details, How your 7-segment display is working ? What are the pins `DIG1`, `DIG2`, etc ?

After a quick look on the internet, I found this web site: 
At some point, it states that : [Arduino: Using C to write 7 Segment 4 Bit Display Driver](https://blog.monotok.org/arduino-using-c-to-write-7-segment-4-bit-display-driver/)

> The right hand most 4 bits are the `DIG0`, `DIG1`, `DIG2` and `DIG3`. These control which display unit displays the previous 8 bits.

So I guess you actually have 4 seven segments display and the `DIGx` pins are enabling the changes on the x seven segments display.

Whatever the `DIGx` pin utilities, if you want to be able to control those pin in your code, you can add 4 signals `STD_LOGIC` in the port section of your seven_segment entity declaration. You can also add a single `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR` of length 4 in the port section of your `seven_segment` entity declaration (what I did below).

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL; 

entity seven_segments is
port(
    clk       : in  std_logic;
    bcd       : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);   -- BCD input
    dig_pins  : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);   -- DIGx pins output
    segment7  : out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0)    -- 7 bit decoded output.
    );
end entity;
--'a' corresponds to MSB of segment7 and g corresponds to LSB of segment7.


architecture Behavioral of seven_segments is

begin

    BCD_process : process (clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            case  bcd is
            when "0000"=> segment7 <="0000001";  -- '0'
            when "0001"=> segment7 <="1001111";  -- '1'
            when "0010"=> segment7 <="0010010";  -- '2'
            when "0011"=> segment7 <="0000110";  -- '3'
            when "0100"=> segment7 <="1001100";  -- '4'
            when "0101"=> segment7 <="0100100";  -- '5'
            when "0110"=> segment7 <="0100000";  -- '6'
            when "0111"=> segment7 <="0001111";  -- '7'
            when "1000"=> segment7 <="0000000";  -- '8'
            when "1001"=> segment7 <="0000100";  -- '9'
             --nothing is displayed when a number more than 9 is given as input.
            when others=> segment7 <="1111111";
            end case;
        end if;
    end process;

    DIG_pins_process : process (clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            --Do whatever you want with the signals DIGx if you need to
        end if;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

The pin 133 is the name of the physical pin that links your FPGA logic to the pin DIG1 of your seven segment display; it should be specified in the constraint file. I personally use Vivado on Xilinx, and they have an XDC file that specifies the constraint:

```
set_property PACKAGE_PIN 133 [get_ports dig_pins[1]]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports dig_pins[1]]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN 135 [get_ports dig_pins[2]]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports dig_pins[2]]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN 136 [get_ports dig_pins[3]]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports dig_pins[3]]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN 137 [get_ports dig_pins[4]]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports dig_pins[4]]
```

You probably have something similar on the Altera development software.

For xilinx device using Vivado, you can perform the tutorial here: [HDL Design using Vivado](https://www.xilinx.com/support/university/vivado/vivado-teaching-material/hdl-design.html). You have to do the **Lab1 - Modeling Concepts** (there are a PDF and a bunch of files in a archive to download). You will find an example **Model a BCD to 7-Segment Decoder** at paragraph 5.2.

For Altera, you have to do your own research, but it seems that the syntax is describe here: [Assigning Pins](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/support/support-resources/design-software/max_plus-ii/pin.html)

I also want to point out that the number pin 133, 135, etc might be the name of the pins of the developement board and not the name of the pins of the FPGA chip. You will probably have to look into the documentation of your bord and your FPGA chip to find the right name.

*Some more advices:*

- You do not use the right libraries, you should use use `IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;` and use `IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;` only, the others are not official IEEE standard, for more information of on libraries: [Standard VHDL Packages](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/stdpkg.html) and [When to use VHDL library std_logic_unsigned and numeric_std?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704135/when-to-use-vhdl-library-std-logic-unsigned-and-numeric-std)
- `end seven_segments;` can be replace by `end entity;` without the name of the entity, I believe it is more clear that way.
- `end Behavioural;` can be replaced by `end architecture;` without the name of the architecture, I believe it is more clear that way.
- you should use `rising_edge(clk)` instead of `(clk'event and clk='0')`, not only it is more clear, but your formulation has some drawback explained here: [Difference between rising_edge(clk) and (clk'event and clk='1')](http://vhdlguru.blogspot.com/2010/04/difference-between-risingedgeclk-and.html)
- All of your code in synchronous, so your sensitivity list, you should only have your clock `clk` and not `BCD`. You have plenty of explanation on the internet, among them: [How to create a process with a sensitivity list in VHDL](https://vhdlwhiz.com/sensitivity-list/) and [When must a signal be inserted into the sensitivity list of a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991223/when-must-a-signal-be-inserted-into-the-sensitivity-list-of-a-process)

Comment: First of all, thank you for the elaborate answer. You were right the DIG1,DIG2,DIG3,DIG4 refer to the 4 different 7 Segment displays of the Board.
Also, thank you for the tips! Now regarding your code, the DIGx pins should be used as outputs.
[Here](https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2F1drv.ms%2Ff%2Fs!Ar3VgAmjw82yiPQQLC6MsLQOBoWvnA%3Ffbclid%3DIwAR1d3b92PhjHBqdx6jH0nxMW7H_6aaihv4kgT3tEK35oWJp2hH1jm27Rf9Y&h=AT02vS1vZojqzhQCh2Ma_S1bvrlm-PKMoinDw2zR6m1YJTU0QgRNRtycK7Bmuabn05dwugkMEXUd8JafhZZCtirjlQ606fywP5m6U2MXu0meqZFDRUyLOtV-ZMb1xWjizURckw) can be found the full schematics.

Comment: I cannot see your schematic (I cannot go on certain site, yours is one of them), but you are right, `dig_pins` is an output, my bad. Do you need other explanations ?